# Wordpress taxonomy attachment

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I created to add attachment for a custom taxonomy. It works, but i don't know how can I print the taxonomy with the attachment.

```
function add_stars_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'star', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_stars_to_attachments' );`
```

this is the function for attachment

I want to print the taxonomy terms something like this:

> [attachment] - [term_name]

Have someone any idea?

Answer (score 2):

WP have beautiful codex [See this guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

Or if You want make own "custom" html use [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) (pseudocode)

You can see all related to Taxonomy data in `$term` object

```
 $terms = get_terms( 'star' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';

     }
     echo '</ul>';
 }
```

Comment: Yes, with this i'll print only term name, but i want to display the attachement and the name `$term->attachement - $term->name` something like this, but `$term->attachement` deson't exist

Comment: attachments stored on post_meta tables, and you have Taxonomy_id you can simply get taxonomy metadata with this ID

Comment: 'object(WP_Term)#385 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(30) ["name"]=> string(4) "2015" ["slug"]=> string(4) "2015" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(30) ["taxonomy"]=> string(12) "release-year" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(38) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }'

Comment: you need try this solution http://kucrut.org/wordpress-attachment-category-terms/

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I added the attachment to content of taxonomy and i print this with `$term->description`